# Testing Function with Multiple Coroutine Delays

Tags: android, kotlin, delay, kotlin-coroutines

Could someone please advise how to assert on lines of code which are behind coroutine delays in functions. I am unable to do this using injected `dispatchers` and using `runBlockingTest`. I have also updated my projects dependency and tried using the newer `runTest` to no avail.

Please could someone advise.

Code Example:

```
val liveData1 = MutableLiveData(false)

fun foo() {
    doTheThing(liveData1, {lambda1(liveData1)})
}

fun doTheThing(liveData1: LiveData<Boolean>, f1: () -> Unit) {
    if (!liveData1.value) {
        f1()
    } 
}

fun lambda1(liveData1: LiveData<Boolean>) {
    viewModelScope.launch(dispatchers.main) {
        delay(1000)
        liveData1.postValue(true)
        delay(1000)
        liveData1.postValue(false)
    }
}
```

Test Example:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Test `test doTheThing`() = runBlockingTest{
    val subject = MyClass(TestCoroutineDispatchers())
    
    val observer1 = subject.liveData1.test()

    observers1.assertValueHistory(false)
    
    subject.foo()

    observers1.assertValueHistory(false, true, false) // fails here stating should have history [false]!=[false, true, false]
}
```

I have checked this and if I set the delays as 0, then my assertions are correct. I have gone through the debugger and the tests always runs the code down to the first delay, but never reaches the code past the delay.

LiveData testing helper functions:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.test(): TestObserver<T> = TestObserver.test(this)

********

public TestObserver<T> assertValueHistory(T... values) {
    List<T> mValueHistory = valueHistory();
    int size = mValueHistory.size();
    if (size != values.length) {
        throw fail("Value count differs; expected: " + values.length + " " + Arrays.toString(values)
                + " but was: " + size + " " + this.valueHistory);
    }

    for (int valueIndex = 0; valueIndex < size; valueIndex++) {
        T historyItem = mValueHistory.get(valueIndex);
        T expectedItem = values[valueIndex];
        if (notEquals(expectedItem, historyItem)) {
            throw fail("Values at position " + valueIndex + " differ; expected: " + valueAndClass(expectedItem) + " but was: " + valueAndClass(historyItem));
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to use the following dispatcher. The TestCoroutineDispatcher() alone isn't enough...

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@InternalCoroutinesApi
object SynchronousDispatchersWithNoDelay : Dispatchers {

    override val io: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = NoDelayDispatcher()

    override val main: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = NoDelayDispatcher()

    class NoDelayDispatcher : CoroutineDispatcher(), Delay {

        override fun scheduleResumeAfterDelay(timeMillis: Long, continuation: CancellableContinuation<Unit>) { 
            continuation.resume(Unit) {} 
        }

        override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
            block.run()
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Dispatchers is an interface I defined. I already has SynchronousDispatcher for testing purposes, but it didn't handle the delay in testing issue I had. The interface and other implementations are below:

**Interface:**

```
interface Dispatchers {

    val io: CoroutineDispatcher
    val main: CoroutineDispatcher
}
```

**Implementation for use in code:**

```
object DispatchersImpl : Dispatchers {

    override val io: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.IO

    override val main: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.Main
}
```

**Implementation for use in tests:**
This is the one I tried to use first which I describe above as "not enough"

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
object SynchronousDispatchers : Dispatchers {

    override val io: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    override val main: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
}
```

Comment: for me it's not working. Dispatchers is a Singleton now. So, the error is that cannot inherit from a Singleton

Comment: Dispatchers is an interface I defined. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is wrapping the Dispatcher in an interface.

```
interface IDispatcherProvider{
   val main : Dispatcher
   val io : Dispatcher
   val default: Dispatcher
   val unconfined: Dispatcher
}
```

This allows the deployment of your code to have :

```
object DispatcherProvider : IDispatcherProvider{
   val main : Dispatcher = Dispatchers.Main
   val io : Dispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
   val default: Dispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
   val unconfined: Dispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined
}
```

Then you pass around the interface so that you can inject the TestProvider:

```
object TestDispatcherProvider : IDispatcherProvider{
   val main : Dispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
   val io : Dispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
   val default: Dispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
   val unconfined: Dispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
}
```

This way your test will not use the thread pool but will run sequentially. There is another way around this that follows the same premise were you reassign the dispatcher, but I cannot remember what it is and this is very close (used a DI to pass around) to what we did and has been working well for our coroutine test.
So in your class :

```
class SomeClass(private val dispatcher: IDispatcherProvider = DispatcherProvider){
val liveData1 = MutableLiveData(false)

fun foo() {
    doTheThing(liveData1, {lambda1(liveData1)})
}

fun doTheThing(liveData1: LiveData<Boolean>, f1: () -> Unit) {
    if (!liveData1.value) {
        f1()
    } 
}

fun lambda1(liveData1: LiveData<Boolean>) {
    viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher.main) {
        delay(1000)
        liveData1.postValue(true)
        delay(1000)
        liveData1.postValue(false)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. When I said in my question I was unable to do this with injected dispatchers and runBlockingTest I did mean I had already tried injecting the TestCoroutineDispatcher() using your method described. 

I have found a solution - posted below.